# Is it correct that $\arg(z^n)=n\arg(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For a complex number $z\ne0$, $Arg(z)$ is the unique angle $-\pi<\theta\le\pi$ so that $z=re^{i\theta}$, where $r=|z|$. On the other hand, $\arg(z)$ is the collection of values $Arg(z)+2k\pi$ for $k=0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots$, i.e. $\arg(z)=\{\theta+2k\pi\mid k=0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots\}$.

One of my tutorial questions that confuses me is:

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that $\arg(z^n)=n\arg(z)$.

The following is the solution provided by the coordinator.

> Write $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then $z^n=r^ne^{in\theta}$. Thus
> $\arg(z^n)=n\theta=n\arg(z)$.

I am not sure whether this solution is correct or not. I am not even sure if the claim in the question is correct or not.

As $\arg{z}$ is a set, I interpret $n\arg(z)$ as the set $\{n\phi\mid\phi\in\arg(z)\}$. I then rewrite \begin{align}
\{n\phi\mid\phi\in\arg(z)\}&=\{n(\theta+2k\pi)\mid k=0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots\}\\&=\{n\theta+2nk\pi\mid k=0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots\}
\end{align}

On the other hand, \begin{align}\arg(z^n)=\{n\theta+2k_1\pi\mid k_1=0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots\}\end{align}

It is pretty clear that the above two sets are not equal, as $k_1$ may not be a multiple of $n$.

Some other "proofs" that I found online use the fact that $\arg(z_1z_2)=\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)$ and proceed by induction. I think the problem behind these proofs is that, for a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $A+A\ne2A$. Here $A+A=\{a_1+a_2\mid a_1,a_2\in A\}$ and $2A=\{2a\mid a\in A\}$.

I can see that the point of this question is to provide students an easier way to calculate high power of a complex number. But I think a better way to formulate the idea is to write
$$Arg(z^n)=nArg(z) \text{ mod to the interval }(-\pi,\pi],$$
or
$$nArg(z)\in\arg(z^n).$$

Comment: The use of the “equals” symbol and interpretation as sets is confusing. Instead, think of equality mod $2 \pi$, i.e. $a = b \pmod{2\pi}$ if and only if $a-b$ is an integral multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: If you want, just write $\arg(z^n) = n\arg(z) + 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ instead.  I'm not convinced it's useful spending too much time on though...

Comment: Ya but when teaching students and when they asked, I want things to be correct but not confusing...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of interpreting $n\arg z$ as $\{n\theta:\theta\in\arg z\}$, you should interpret it as $\{n\theta+2\pi k:\theta\in\arg z,k\in\Bbb Z\}$.

Using sets instead of single values in this context is just a way to capture the fact that angles that differ by a multiple of $2\pi$ are equivalent. If $z=e^{i\theta}$ then $z^n=e^{in\theta}$, and so of course $e^{i(n\theta+2\pi k)}$ is also equal to $z^n$ for any $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Use De Moivre's theorem: if $z=|z|(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)\,\,$ then

$z^n=|z|^{n}(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))$.

Clearly

$\arg(z)=\theta+2k\pi$ and $\arg(z^{n})=n\theta+2m\pi$. So

$n\arg(z)=n\theta+2kn\pi$ .Thus,

$\arg(z^{n})=n\arg(z)\pmod{2\pi\mathbb{Z}}$. This is the correct rigorous statement!

Trying to prove equality of sequences is simply hopeless!